# MongoDB Query plan not using compound index

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-explain

I am trying MongoDB with a dataset about the company profile margin for learning purpose. Here is the sample document

```
{
    "parent_comp" : 1
    "child_comp" : 101
    "profit" : NumberLong(70320020)
}
```

I have created two indexes i.e one on child_comp field and the other one is a compound index with parent_comp, child_comp, and last_outage_timestamp.

For the below query, I executed the *explain* command to see the query plan.

```
  MongoDB Enterprise > db.data.find({ "$and" : [{ "parent_comp" : 951, "child_comp" : 9351, "profit" : { "$gte" : { "$numberLong" : "500000000" } } }, { "profit" : { "$lte" : { "$numberLong" : "1000000000" } } }] }).sort({"profit" : 1}).limit(3).explain();
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "test.data",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "$and" : [
                {
                    "child_comp" : {
                        "$eq" : 9351
                    }
                },
                {
                    "parent_comp" : {
                        "$eq" : 951
                    }
                },
                {
                    "profit" : {
                        "$lte" : {
                            "$numberLong" : "1000000000"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "profit" : {
                        "$gte" : {
                            "$numberLong" : "500000000"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "queryHash" : "B570EF0C",
        "planCacheKey" : "187EF74B",
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "LIMIT",
            "limitAmount" : 3,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "filter" : {
                    "$and" : [
                        {
                            "child_comp" : {
                                "$eq" : 9351
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "parent_comp" : {
                                "$eq" : 951
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "profit" : 1
                    },
                    "indexName" : "profit_index",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "multiKeyPaths" : {
                        "profit" : [ ]
                    },
                    "isUnique" : false,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : false,
                    "indexVersion" : 2,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "profit" : [
                            "[{ $numberLong: \"500000000\" }, { $numberLong: \"1000000000\" }]"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [
            {
                "stage" : "SORT",
                "sortPattern" : {
                    "profit" : 1
                },
                "limitAmount" : 3,
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "filter" : {
                            "$and" : [
                                {
                                    "parent_comp" : {
                                        "$eq" : 951
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "profit" : {
                                        "$lte" : {
                                            "$numberLong" : "1000000000"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "profit" : {
                                        "$gte" : {
                                            "$numberLong" : "500000000"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "child_comp" : 1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "child_comp_index",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                "child_comp" : [ ]
                            },
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 2,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "child_comp" : [
                                    "[9351.0, 9351.0]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "stage" : "LIMIT",
                "limitAmount" : 3,
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                        "keyPattern" : {
                            "parent_comp" : 1,
                            "child_comp" : 1,
                            "profit" : 1
                        },
                        "indexName" : "parent_comp_1_child_comp_1_profit_1",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "multiKeyPaths" : {
                            "parent_comp" : [ ],
                            "child_comp" : [ ],
                            "profit" : [ ]
                        },
                        "isUnique" : false,
                        "isSparse" : false,
                        "isPartial" : false,
                        "indexVersion" : 2,
                        "direction" : "forward",
                        "indexBounds" : {
                            "parent_comp" : [
                                "[951.0, 951.0]"
                            ],
                            "child_comp" : [
                                "[9351.0, 9351.0]"
                            ],
                            "profit" : [
                                "[{ $numberLong: \"500000000\" }, { $numberLong: \"1000000000\" }]"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "localhost",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "4.2.8",
        "gitVersion" : "43d25888249164d76d5e04dd6cf38f6111e21f5f"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

As you can see winning plan used single index instead of compound index. So could you please let me know why compound index was not used.

Comment: Run explain with the "allPlansExecution" option so you can see the execution time and number of documents examined for each plan.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is sorting on profit, and the compound index does not include the field you are sorting on hence using the compound index would necessitate an  additional sort stage.

The trade-offs and reasoning is further explained [in the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/).

See also https://www.alexbevi.com/blog/2020/05/16/optimizing-mongodb-compound-indexes-the-equality-sort-range-esr-rule/.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but compound index i.e. parent_comp_1_child_comp_1_profit_1 includes profit field as well. Let me know if I missed something here

Comment: I think I missed that. In this case please make an mcve and start by reducing your index and query to two fields.